# will_paginate for group query with sunspot 2.2.2 in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot, sunspot-solr

I am using sunspot 2.2.2 in my rails app for searching results, 
I have this code for grouping in my model:

```
def self.search_products(params, currency = nil, page_uri = nil)
  search_products = Sunspot.search(VariantPrice) do
   group :code do 
    if params[:gallery_order].present?
      order_by :price, params[:gallery_order].downcase.to_sym
    elsif params[:new_arrival].present? || params[:name] == "new-arrivals"
      order_by :product_created_at, :desc
    else
      if params[:fashion_type] == "fashion"
        order_by :price, :asc
      elsif params[:sort] != "lowhigh"
        order_by :price, :asc
      else
        order_by :price, :asc
      end
    end
    limit 1
  end
end
```

and I have this code in my controller :

```
variant_prices = Product.search_products(params, @currency, request.original_fullpath)

@variant_prices = []
variant_prices.group(:code).groups.each do |group|
  group.results.each do |result|
    @variant_prices << result       
  end
end
@variant_prices = @variant_prices.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => PER_PAGE_VALUE)
@variant_prices_count = variant_prices.group(:code).total
```

now I am getting the expected count that is @variant_prices_count, which is 1400 in my case, but I am getting @variant_prices count as 60 which is wrong in my case , here I was expecting to get 1400.and then I want to paginate with this result. cant understand whether it's will_paginate issue or something else.
Help!

Comment: What is your PER_PAGE_VALUE value set as?

Comment: variant_prices.group(:code).total gives 1400 count as result and i want to paginate it on 1400 results data but in final result i am getting 60 values only

Comment: it has by default 19 values

Answer (score 1):

You can get 1400 from the paginate instance also by [Total entries](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mislav/will_paginate/WillPaginate/Collection#total_entries-instance_method)

by this way replace `count` with `total_entries`

```
@variant_prices = @variant_prices.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => PER_PAGE_VALUE)
@variant_prices.total_entries#it will return toal entries 1400
```